# In PHP, when to use arrays and when to use multiple variables?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

For a given dataset - In terms of memory, efficiency and readability - when it is better to use an array, and when it is better to declare multiple variables? What are the pros and cons of using each?

It is - I believe - a fundamental question in programming, and it may have different answers for different programming languages, but the  focus is on the PHP point of view (especially regarding the memory management).

**EDIT (Example to clarify):**

If I have a user, and I want to store his username and password, should I do it in a `$user` array, or in two variables - `$username` and `$password`? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: Use array when you need an array. Use variable when you need a variable.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký But when you can use both - which of them should you use? I will add an example to the question so the question will be clearer.

Comment: Yes, with example it’d be easier to help.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký, I added an example. Please read it and contribute an answer. I will really appriciate it. And do not forget to rank up the question. ;) Thank you.

Comment: Your example isn't appropriate. You can have credentials as separate variables or in array. In this case it doesn't matter. My advice would be: Just write code and when you're not sure if use variable or array, ask there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to store more than 1 value in a variable, use array. But if you want to store only one vale in a variable, use normal variable.

**EX:**

```
$a = 10;// one value so variable.
```

Suppose you want to add all multiples of 5 till 20, then use arrays.

```
$a = array(5,10,15,20);
```

While storing more than 1 value, if you use differsnt variables, its not a good practice.

```
$a = 5;
$b = 10;
$c = 15;
$d = 20;
```

The above mentioned is wrong, you should use arrays.

**Finally:**

`An array is a special variable, which can hold more than one value at a time.`

`An variable is a normal variable, which can hold only one value at a time.`

Irrespective of different languages, concept remains same. It will be up to developer to use `array` or a normal `variable`.

**EDIT:**

As far my understanding, 2 variables will not create any issue with memory.

You can go ahead with variables. If you want to store more values , then use arrays.

**But keep in mind that variables are faster that arrays.**

Comment: As of PHP 5.4 you can define arrays using the new method `$a = [5, 10, 15, 20];`.

Comment: I just gave a sample example. But there are many ways of declaring it. But still i accept your suggession.

Comment: I edited the question and added an example, please read it and review your answer. And do not forget to rank up the question. ;) Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for editing. So you are saying that the length of the dataset is a factor in the answer. Well, when it is to big to be in variables? What other factors there are?

Comment: see this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337685/php-many-variables-or-one-array. even for 5 variables, variables memory is less. It all comes down to our requirement. also see this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785691/too-many-variables-vs-arrays

Comment: @Niranjan N Raju Oh! Thank you very much! I searched for this kind of question. It is basicly the same question as I asked, but still has more votes. :( Could you edit your answer with the conclusion so Other people could Benefit too without have the trouble of reading the comments?